# Parse XML received from a GET request

Tags: php, xml, dom, curl

As a part of a school project, i am making a call of the school's api.

Method:  GET
Response Format: Xml

Now i use curl to make the web request.

```
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

$data=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Now how do i parse the xml output to get the data i want?

Hope the question is clear

Comment: Parsing XML with PHP has been asked about many times before: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parse+xml+php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the exact nature of the content and, moreover, its structure.

The basics are to use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) (or, alternatively, `simplexml`, which I dislike as an API) to parse the document, then to use DOM traversal or XPath to find the content you want.

An example might look like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($data); // data from cURL request

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$names = $xpath->query('//student/name'); // find all name elements that are direct children of student elements

foreach ($names as $name) {
    echo $name->nodeValue;
}
```

The exact code you want depends on the structure of the XML and what content you want to get out of it.

Comment: Error:

DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Empty string supplied as input

Comment: @Saurabh My guess is that you're supplying an empty string. For some reason, the cURL request in your question is not returning data. Fix that, then try this again.

Comment: managed to make it work.  After hours of struggle I found that I have no certificates to verify against on my local machine, so if anyone runs into a problem add : curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false;

Answer (score 1):

Use [SimpleXML](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples.php):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), [`XMLParser`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) and [`XPath`](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp). I usually prefer `SimpleXML`, but as many people, as many opinions...

You will find lots of examples in the documentation to this PHP classes.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that $data contains xml you can use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to parse it